# Images in my s3 bucket will not open in the browser, they will only download

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I open an image on my s3 bucket in the browser?

I have setup an Amazon s3 bucket to host my webapp's images, the issue I am having is that when I click on the image's link, it will download the image instead of displaying it in the browser.

1. I have set the metadata to be 'Content-Type: image/*'
2. I have set the permissions to be public

This is the code I am using:

```
private void uploadFileTos3bucket(String fileName, MultipartFile file) 
{ 
    try
        (InputStream is = file.getInputStream()) 
            { ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata(); 
              metadata.setContentLength(file.getBytes().length); 
              metadata.setLastModified(new Date()); 
              metadata.setContentType("image/*"); s3client.putObject(new 
              PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, is, metadata).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)); }        
              catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
    }
```

Does anyone have any other ideas or solutions?

Comment: can you provide us witht the code that you already tried and didnt work ?

Comment: It has been posted above

Comment: can you change `image png content type` to `image/png` and try the code again?

Comment: `image/*` is not a useful content type. `image/jpeg` is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `Content-Type` to `image/png`, considering that your image in S3 is in `.png` format. You need to set the appropriate content type as set in your S3 bucket. For example, if it is a text, set it as `text/plain`. Similarly for image, set it to `image/png`. Also, your file content type should not be `binary/octet-stream`, otherwise, it won't open up, rather it will download then.